# How to do every Http request authentication in .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

My project is created in .NET framework 4.5. I want to validate `HttpContext` is not null on every http request.

I know two possibilities here:

1. I have `Global.asax.cs` file, but in this file I can't access `HttpContext` object. Is there any way to do this?
2. Can I make custom authentication filter and use filter on methods called from `ProcessRequest()`.

How to register custom filter in `Global.asax.cs` file?

For example:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    string requestEndPoint= context.Request["CBH"];
    string response = "";

    switch (requestEndPoint)
    {
        case "GetData": 
            GetEmployeeData(); 
            break;
    }
}

[CustomFilter]    // This can be class to validate HttpContext or Session object.
public void GetEmployeeData()
{
    // some code ....
}
```